# Run as simple perl script in NetBean using Java language

Tags: java, perl, netbeans

I am in the progress of learning perl language. 
I have made a simple perl script (as shown as below).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "hi Lala\n";
```

I am trying to run this script in NetBean using java language.
My code is as below:

```
public class javaProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process process;

        try
        {
            String testFile = "perl C:\\Strawberry\\perl_tests\\hello_world.pl";
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(testFile);
            process.getOutputStream();

            process.waitFor();
            if(process.exitValue() == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Command Successful");

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Command Failure");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+ e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

But I got this error

> Exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "perl C:\Strawberry\perl_tests\hello_world.pl": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I have save the script as hello_world.pl in the directory as shown above. So, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Is it NetBean problem? The script problem? But when I run the script using Strawberry IDE, there is no problem or errors.

Comment: perl is not found!! Add the full path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`perl` is not found. 
in your script you are refer to `#!/usr/bin/perl` wich is not existence in a Windows path. So you have to add the complete path to perl Interpreter.

```
String testFile = "<path_to_perl>perl C:\\Strawberry\\perl_tests\\hello_world.pl";
```

Also add the correct path in your perl script:

```
#!<path_to_perl>perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "hi Lala\n";
```

Comment: Now, I got 'Command Successful' after adding the path to perl.
But I still cannot see the expected output 'hi Lala'
Any advice? Thanks

Comment: I put in this line of code `OutputStream outs = process.getOutputStream();
System.out.println("Outs: "+ outs);`
The output is `Outs: java.io.BufferedOutputStream@6e8cf4c6`
Why isn't it in strings?

Comment: @Kristin.Y Because of the implementation of the `toString()` method. Read about you have to use an OutputStream

Comment: Ok. Got it!
Thanks a lot for your help